# Laravel 5 access tagged cache

Tags: caching, tags, laravel-5

I have just read the documentation about 5.0 cache and tags.
So can I access cache by it's key even though I created it with tags?

It seems strange to me, that I couldn't do it:

```
\Cache::tags('tag1','tag2')->put("John","John data",10);

\Cache::tags('tag1','tag2')->get("John"); // ==> Gives "John data"
\Cache::get("John"); // ==> Gives null
```

So the tags are becoming actually a part of the key?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used tags, but the [4.2 docs have the following](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache#cache-tags)

> To access a tagged cache, pass the same ordered list of tags used to save it.
>
> $anne = Cache::tags('people', 'artists')->get('Anne');

P.S: I know you are using 5.0, but the docs say nothing about tags so I'm assuming it's been kept untouched.

Comment: Well, yeah. I can access cache by key AND tags. But if I use only get like this I get null: 
    \Cache::get("John");

Comment: Yes, I meant it seems to be ok to get null. The docs say you have to use the tags to get the info, you cant just use the key.